# Rest parameter problems

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, parameters

I'm attempting to have a class inherit a rest parameter from a parent class. Unfortunately for some reason the inherited rest parameter's inputs are treated as one whole index rather than each one acting like its own index.

Here's the code for the parent class with a rest parameter that works properly:

```
package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;

public class SubClassText extends ClassText {
    protected var parentText:ClassText;
    protected var setStatValues;
    protected var className:String;
    protected var classType:int;

    public function SubClassText(textKey:String, textName:String, stageInstance:Stage, isVisible:Boolean, alignToObject:Object, direction:String, xDistance:Number, yDistance:Number, onOverText:String, parentText:ClassText, className:String, classType:int, ... setStatValues) {
        super(textKey, textName, stageInstance, isVisible, alignToObject, direction, xDistance, yDistance, onOverText);
        this.parentText = parentText;
        this.parentText.subClassArray.push(this);
        this.setStatValues = setStatValues;
        this.className = className;
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    //Called when the player clicks this object
    override protected function onClick(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace(this.setStatValues.length);
        Entity.getEntity("entityName", "player").setStat("className", this.className);
        Entity.getEntity("entityName", "player").setStat("classType", this.classType);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < this.setStatValues.length; i++) {
            Entity.getEntity("entityName", "player").setStat(Main.statArray[i], this.setStatValues[i]);
        }
        Main.setClassVisibility(this.parentText.subClassArray, true);
    }

    //Adds this object to it's parent's class array
    override protected function addToArray() {
        Main.subClasses.push(this);
    }
}
}
```

I have the `trace()` call in the onClick listener to see the length of the rest parameter. In all instances of this class the rest parameter returns the proper amount of inputs (in this case, 5 since that's how many stats an entity has).

And here's the class that extends this parent class:

```
package {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class AllySubClassText extends SubClassText {
    private var displayName:String;

    public function AllySubClassText(textKey:String, textName:String, stageInstance:Stage, isVisible:Boolean, alignToObject:Object, direction:String, xDistance:Number, yDistance:Number, onOverText:String, parentText:ClassText, displayName:String, className:String, classType:int, ... setStatValues) {
        super(textKey, textName, stageInstance, isVisible, alignToObject, direction, xDistance, yDistance, onOverText, parentText, className, classType, setStatValues);
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    //Called when the player clicks this object
    override protected function onClick(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace(this.setStatValues.length);
        Main.tryAddAlly(this.displayName, this.className, this.classType, this.setStatValues);
        Main.setAllyVisibility(this.parentText.subClassArray, true);
    }

    //Adds this object to it's parent's class array
    override protected function addToArray() {
        Main.allySubClasses.push(this);
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I have the same rest parameter and the same `trace()` call.

For a better understanding here's an example piece of an instance of SubClassText:

```
var beserker:SubClassText = new SubClassText("beserker", "Beserker", stage, false,
warrior, "downCenter", 0, 0, "Beserkers are crazy strong fighters", warrior, "Beserker", 
0, 15, 5, 10, 10, 10);
```

Then I can go into that SubClassText and trace its rest parameter length (setStatValues, I'm going to trace it from the fla document so for now I'm going to make that parameter `public` instead of `protected`):

```
trace(beserker.setStatValues.length); //5
```

Now here's an example of an instance of AllySubClassText:

```
var knight:AllySubClassText = new AllySubClassText("knight", "War: The Knight", 
stage, false, warriors, "downCenter", 0, 0, "War is a strong Knight", warriors, "War",
"Knight", 0, 15, 5, 10, 10, 10);
```

Then when I trace the knight instance's rest parameter length:

```
trace(knight.setStatValues.length); //1
```

The example pieces were taken directly from my code, I just shortened the onHover string so it's easier to read. Sorry for the huge amount of inputs on the classes, UI code quickly took a lot of parameters to work correctly. I'm not sure why all inputs are being treated as one index rather than individual indexes. I even know it's doing this because here's what happens when I trace just the rest parameter:

```
trace(knight.setStatValues + ", " + knight.setStatValues.length); //15,5,10,10,10, 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It could be a minor oversight, but I'm stumped right now.

Comment: A workaround I just found was to reset the inherited setStatValues variable in the child class. I guess that's fine, just thought the inherited variable should've worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `...rest` parameters are an array.
That means when you pass that array to yet another function as a `...rest` parameter, it will be of length 1, because you only passed one parameter: the single array.

It doesn't automatically "unwrap" an array into its elements.

Try this:

```
function first(...firstRest):void
{
    trace(firstRest.length);
    second(firstRest);
}

function second(...secondRest):void
{
    trace(secondRest.length);
}

first(1,2,3);
```

I wouldn't recommend using `...rest` anyway.
Create a class that holds all the status variables and pass an object of that class to the constructor. That allows you to do boundary checks on the values, dispatch change events to update views displaying the stats, etc.

These constructor calls you show there look quite bloated.
Passing a configuration object will help in reducing the mess.

Comment: Yeah I basically shoved all the code from the fla to classes, trying to shave as much as I could from that fla. This UI text uses a few different classes to do multiple things so the number of input variables is going to be quite large. In the beginning I didn't use the rest parameter anyway because I'm probably only going to have a set amount of stats in the whole game, but in the name of flexibility I put a varying amount just in case I wanted to add more in the future.

Comment: Moving code into classes this way will not provide the benefits of object orientation. You will very likely get frustrated and will  even more likely not see the point of writing code in classes. Super flexible do-everything, be-prepared-for-everything classes aren't the way to go either. Coding paradigms yield benefits, but only if you follow the paradigm. How to transition your existing time line code into class based code is a good question in itself.